# Unable to install expo-app-loading using expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

Upon running the expo install expo-app-loading I get this error message

```
396 verbose cwd C:\{path}
397 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
398 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "expo-app-loading"
399 verbose node v14.17.5
400 verbose npm  v6.14.14
401 error code ENOENT
402 error syscall rename
403 error path C:\{path}\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\node_modules\node-fetch
404 error dest C:\{path}\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\node_modules\.node-fetch.DELETE
405 error errno -4058
406 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\{path}\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\node_modules\node-fetch' -> 'C:\{path}\node_modules\@expo\image-utils\node_modules\.node-fetch.DELETE'
407 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
408 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I have also tried the standard npm install but that comes to the same conclusion. Should I create a blank file or do I need to install a prerequisit?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node-modules`

`mpn cache clean --force`

`npm install`

`expo install expo-app-loading`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with npm:

`npm install expo-app-loading@1.1.2`

or with `--save` flag:

`expo install expo-app-loading --save`